# Ubuntu global keyboard shortcuts stop working when Terminal is active

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, gnome

I'm trying to get global shortcuts working everywhere for this GNOME extension: https://github.com/mzur/gnome-shell-wsmatrix/

I have set the shortcuts as follows:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['<Control><Alt><Super>Left']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['<Control><Alt><Super>Right']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['<Control><Alt><Super>Up']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['<Control><Alt><Super>Down']"
```

Which works fine *except when a terminal is active*.

Then instead of switching workspace the shortcuts will produce `ABCD` in the terminal.

It's the same result in the default Ubuntu Terminal app and others like Tilix.

Is there a fix for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it was https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto/ causing the issue.

Edit: Kinto is an app that modifies keyboard layout and I use it to make an Apple Keyboard behave like on MacOS.

Once I uninstalled Kinto I didn't have problems navigation workspaces with global shortcuts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).